# String search in bytes stream

Tags: c++, c++11

I have below program where I trying to search a substring in const unsigned char * byte

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

const unsigned char bytes[] = { 
        0x49, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x49, 0x54, 0x45, 0x20, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x40, 0x76
        , 0x6f, 0x64, 0x61, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x75, 0x6b, 0x20, 0x53, 0x49, 0x50, 0x2f, 0x32
        , 0x2e, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x56, 0x69, 0x61, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x53, 0x49, 0x50, 0x2f, 0x32, 0x2e, 0x30
        , 0x2f, 0x55, 0x44, 0x50, 0x20, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x38, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x36
        , 0x38, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x30, 0x36, 0x31, 0x3b, 0x62, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x68, 0x3d, 0x7a, 0x39
        , 0x68, 0x47, 0x34, 0x62, 0x4b, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x32, 0x31, 0x38, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x0d
        , 0x0a, 0x46, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70, 0x70, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70
        , 0x3a, 0x62, 0x62, 0x40, 0x6a, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x3e, 0x3b, 0x74, 0x61, 0x67
        , 0x3d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x32, 0x31, 0x38, 0x53, 0x49, 0x50, 0x70, 0x54, 0x61, 0x67, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31
        , 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x54, 0x6f, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x73, 0x75, 0x74, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x61
        , 0x62, 0x63, 0x40, 0x76, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x61, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x75, 0x6b, 0x3e, 0x0d
        , 0x0a, 0x43, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x44, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x32, 0x31
        , 0x38, 0x40, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x38, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x36, 0x38, 0x0d, 0x0a
        , 0x43, 0x53, 0x65, 0x71, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x31, 0x20, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x49, 0x54, 0x45, 0x0d, 0x0a
        , 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x61, 0x63, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70
        , 0x70, 0x40, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x38, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x36, 0x38, 0x3a, 0x35
        , 0x30, 0x36, 0x31, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x61, 0x78, 0x2d, 0x46, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x77, 0x61, 0x72, 0x64
        , 0x73, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x37, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x53, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6a, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x20
        , 0x50, 0x65, 0x72, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x65, 0x20, 0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74
        , 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x30
        , 0x2e, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x38, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x35, 0x34, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x30, 0x37, 0x30, 0x3b
        , 0x6c, 0x72, 0x3e, 0x2c, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x69, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x61, 0x69, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x2e
        , 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x3b, 0x6c, 0x72, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74
        , 0x2d, 0x54, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69
        , 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x2f, 0x53, 0x44, 0x50, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2d
        , 0x4c, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x74, 0x68, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x0d
        , 0x0a
    };

  const unsigned char* byte = bytes; // this is the buffer received from the other layers
 
  //I am trying to convert it to string using reinterpret_cast
  const std::string charStr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(byte);


  if(!(charStr.find("REGIST")!= std::string::npos)) //the above bytes of character is having this string it should be found in the buffer
  {
     std::cout<<"Not found";
     return;
  }
std::cout<<"found";
return 0;
}
```

But this may cause core dump in high performance systems and find function is also expensive.

What is the best way to serach a string in const unsigned char* buffer?
Let say advance c++ feature not supported.

And what is the best way to solve this problem with old versions of c++(03) and with advance version c++(11)?

Comment: Why should this cause a core dump on high performance systems?

Comment: Your code has a bigger problem in that you are trying to create a `std::string` from a non-null terminated byte array. This invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Your code is also valid in c++03. The construction of str std::string (which is wrong BTW, because of a lacking null terminator) is the part that takes most of the time. If you can use c++17 you can use `std::string_view`. And are you sure `find` is expensive?

Comment: *And what is the best way to solve this problem* -- Questions asking the "best way" are almost never answerable, because what is "best" is highly subjective.

Comment: A bit beyond the `C++03/C++11` scope requested, but in `C++20`, you have [std::boyer_moore_searcher](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher)

Comment: *But this may cause core dump in high performance systems* -- ???  Also, if you need to use an older version of C++ but want to use "newer" features, consider using [boost](https://www.boost.org/).  That library has a Boyer-Moore search algorithm, if you find that the `std::find` is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

The operation may may cause a core dump, because it has Undefined Behaviour - `std::string` expects a pointer to a null-terminated character array, while the array you pass to it is not null-terminated. Because of that, std::string constructor reads through memory outside of the bounds of the buffer until it finds a null terminator - this operation can easily SEGFAULT.

One thing you need to have is length of the buffer. Then you can pass it to the constructor of the string:

```
const std::string charStr{ reinterpret_cast<const char*>(byte), bufferLength };
```

Now, if for some reason this operation turns out to be performance-critical, you most likely don't want to allocate a buffer and copy entire string to it.
To avoid that, you can use `string_view`, either `std::string_view` from c++17 or `absl::string_view` from abseil c++11 library. You pass the same parameters to the constructor, and `string_view` keeps the view to character range, without copying it (mind the lifetime of the buffer!). You can call `find` on `string_view` the same was as on `std::string`.

If you can edit content and size of the buffer though, the easiest way seems to be adding a null-terminator '\0' at the end of the buffer and calling `std::strstr` from `<cstring>`

Answer (score 1):

First way (simple): if you are able to modify your array and to add a \0x00 character at end, you can use the C-function `strstr`.

Second: you can write own version of search function. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a '\0' or 0x00 at the end of your array, your code should work as expected.

You doing a search for a substring, this is 'expensive'. You could implement it by yourself, but it will be quite the same as find.

walk through the byte array and look only for the first letter, if found, compare the rest of the search string. But sounds more or less as a 'find'.